# Manipulating file using Shopify graphql admin api

Tags: shopify-api

I want to delete a file using [deleteFile](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-graphql/2021-10/mutations/fileDelete) method from Shopify sandbox. However deleteFile method is requiring file id and the [File](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-graphql/2022-01/interfaces/File) object doesn't contain id property.

So my question is how do I get file id in shopify graphql ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get Media Image id but an Image id.
So, you can request this type of id using `... on MediaImage`

```
query files($count: Int, $cursor: String) {
  files(first: $count, after: $cursor, sortKey: CREATED_AT, reverse: true) {
    edges {
      cursor
      node {
        ... on MediaImage {
          id
          image {
            height
            width
            url
          }
        }
        __typename
      }
    }
  }
}
```